# return new object of same type as child object in overwritten method

Tags: object, ocaml

I have a virtual super class with several child classes. In the following is a simple example of my situation:

```
(*Super class*)
class virtual super = object(self : 'self)
 method virtual generateNewOne : X
end;;

(*Child class one*)
class subOne = object(self)
 inherit super

 method subOneMethod x =
  x+2;

 method generateNewOne =
  let a = new subOne in
  a
 end;;

(*Child class two*)
class subTwo = object(self)
 inherit super

 method subTwoMethod x =
  x+3;

 method generateNewOne =
  let b = new subTwo in
  b
 end;;
```

My question is:

What do i have to insert for the **X** as type of the generateNewOne method?

My first thought was of type self, but as far as i tried it did not work, because the new objects do not have self type but subOne or subTwo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this if you make `subOne` and `subTwo` classes, since any subclass of them would be returning the wrong type from `generateNewOne`. However, as long as you don't need to subclass further you can define them as plain objects:

```
(*Super class*)
class virtual super = object (self : 'self)
 method virtual generateNewOne : 'self
end

let rec subOne () = object (self)
 inherit super
 method subOneMethod x = x + 2
 method generateNewOne = subOne ()
end

let rec subTwo () = object (self)
 inherit super
 method subTwoMethod x = x + 3
 method generateNewOne = subTwo ()
end
```

Another possibility is to use the "functional objects" syntax, so the object returns a copy of itself (possibly with some fields modified). Then `generateNewOne` will be correct even for subclasses, e.g.

```
class subTwo = object (self)
 inherit super
 method subTwoMethod x = x + 3
 method generateNewOne = {< >}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `X` with `super`. In that case, `generateNewOne` of `subOne` has to return a `super` as well. Which can be achieved with a coercion:

```
method generateNewOne =
  let a = new subOne in
  (a :> super)
```

Similarly for `subTwo`.

If you really insist on `generateNewOne` to return a `subOne` or `subTwo`, then `subOne`, `subTwo` and `super` will be incompatible types, neither being a subtype of another. The reason is that they have mutually different return types of `generateNewOne` (To be more precise, we do not know that of `super` per se, because `X` is not yet specified. But we do know for sure, that `super` will be incompatible with at least one of `subOne` and `subTwo`.). In that case you cannot use inheritance, because inheritance implies that the type of `generateNewOne` remains the same.

Comment: Well thanks so far. Just for my understanding: The moment i say subOne has the method "generateNewOne : subOne" and subTwo has the method "generateNewOne : subTwo" they are no longe subtypes of super, despite the fact that subOne and subTwo inherit super?

Comment: I edited to make it (hopefully) more clear. They are no longer subtypes of super, and for that reason the situation cannot be achieved through inheriting from super.